# Improve regex for capturing files in a directory, excluding dotfiles

Tags: regex

I am looking to get all non dot-files in a folder with a particular extension. So far my regex is:

- [`(?<=\/|^)(?<!\.)(\w+(?:\.mov|\.py|))$`](https://regex101.com/r/RgBT9t/2)

[image]

Is there a way to improve the above regex? What might be some examples where this regex might not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w+` will only match one or more letters, digits or `_`. It will not match the rest of the chars that may constitute a valid file name. Also, your `(?<!\.)` lookbehind is redundant because the previous lookbehind already excludes a dot at that position.

Besides, you do not have to repeat the comma pattern, you may use grouping for extensions only.

You may use

```
(?<=\/|^)([^\/]+)(\.(?:mov|py))$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YLOEs/1)

- `(?<=\/|^)` - `/` or start  of string allowed immediately on the left
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `(\.(?:mov|py))` - Group 2: a `.` char and then either `mov` or `py`
- `$` - end of string/

Note you may also replace `(?<=\/|^)` with `(?<![^\/])` in real code since it will work the same with standalone strings. It will mess the demo results at regex101.com because there, you test against a single multiline string (that is why I added `\n` to the negated character class there, too).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
(?<=\/|^)[^\/\\:*?"<>|\n]+\.(?:mov|py)$
```

- `(?<=\/|^)` Lookbehind just like you had it
- `[^\/\\:*?"<>|\n]+` One or more of any character that is not disallowed in filenames
- `\.` A literal dot
- `(?:mov|py)` Either "mov" or "py" in a non-capturing group (similar to yours, but I moved the dot out and excluded the redundant "|")
- `$` Anchors the search to the end of the line, so only files will match, no folders